# java double print max length

Tags: java

i am curious and searching basic java primitive value "double". it say double is approximately 10^308 length.

but every compile file,

> error: integer number too large: 123456789101115                                                                                 double a= 123456789101115;

**this is my sample:**

```
 public static void main(String []args){

    double a= 123456789101115;

    System.out.println(a);
 }
```

i want when it compile and running, it show 123456789101115.
maybe some people say, why not use long?

actually i want to create calculation like 
output= 0.354 * 123456 (about 15 digit).

And one more, i want all value printout, which mean not using E..
ex: 6.6E9 but i want full ex: 6600000000
any suggest?

Comment: What is happening in your code: you have an int literal value 1234567890101115 first, then assign it into double, which is a process of casting int to double implicitly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indicate that it's a double by adding a `d` or `D` to the end, or a decimal point, or use scientific notation.

```
double a= 123456789101115d; // d
double a= 123456789101115D; // D
double a= 123456789101115.0; // decimal point (you can leave of the final zero)
double a= 123456789101115e0; // scientific notation
```

Numeric literals (numbers) in Java have a type of their own that exists regardless of the variable you assign it to. Using the above methods you can indicate that the number is a double.

Comment: thanks for your answer. almost complete, but when script run, it show:
1.23456789101115E14 
i want value same with my input. not using 1.23456789101115*E14*

Comment: @StevenSugiartoWijaya That's scientific notation, once a number gets over a certain size it will be printed like that. But there are many other ways to format numbers in Java like `NumberFormat`. An easy way to get the output that you want is: `System.out.format("%.0f\n", a);` - this will print the number without a fraction part.

Comment: thank for your help